# Open source HTML-based JMX Client?

Tags: java, jmx

I'm looking for a basic library to give an HTML view of JMX MBeans that I can embed in my Java application.  It sounds like Sun's com.sun.jdmk.comm.HtmlAdaptorServer fits the bill (referenced [here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index.html)).  However, that tool appears to be somewhat license encumbered...

A basic Web UI like that from the referenced article is all I need:
[image]
<sub>(source: [sun.com](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/fig6.gif))</sub>

I am running a servlet container (Jetty), so this library could deploy as a WAR.  But I don't care if it simply opens up its own socket either.

I've looked at [jManage](http://www.jmanage.org/), but it seems not to be designed for embedded use.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

JMinix is pretty cool and seems pretty up-to-date. The UI isn't real deep, but it embeds easily into any servlet container and exposes JMX as REST.

http://code.google.com/p/jminix/

Answer (score 2):

I used MX4J for years. It was reliable and well featured, a really good open source project.

However, I would not recommend it now because

1. Its not being actively maintained
2. It does not fit well with Java 5/6.

To get the best out of it you need to generate annotations with XDoclet and you need to include it on the bootclasspath. If you include it on the bootclasspath you cannot use JConsole because it overrides the JMX routines that come with the JVM.

Why can't you use the Open JDK / Open DMK Http Adaptor? After all OpenJDK is GPL based - isn't it?

Comment: The product I intend to embed the HttpAdaptor is closed source so GPL is not compatible.  The HttpAdaptor would need to be LGPL, MIT, or Apache licensed for our purposes.

Comment: Its only an issue if you intend to modify the HTTP adaptor code then isn't it?

Comment: Decided to use [JDMK](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jmx.html).  It was the best technical option and the legal department approved its use.  Sorry to bog this question down with the legalese :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [MX4J HTTP Adaptor](http://mx4j.sourceforge.net/docs/ch05.html). Unfortunately, it is not packaged as a WAR, but I think it will fit your needs.

//Nicholas

Comment: Nicholas - thanks for the pointer.  I took a look at MX4J but disregarded it due to the same reasons Fortyrunner mentions below.